# Tab panel default Tab not show after the app is logined again

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am working in the sencha touch 2.0. I am unexpectedly facing a problem in the Tab Panel. At the one of my page I have TabPanel with three tabs (By Name, By Department, By Location).They are working fine but when I active the tab By Department and Logout from the app and again come to the This page the deafult activate tab Must be BY NAME. But the active tab is that one which I activated before to logout(By Department).

Comment: Please add some code otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some code? Start with the tab panel. Also, check to see if you have 'autodestroy: false'. If you have that in your config that could be causing a problem. Other than that, its hard to say without seeing how you have it set up. It sounds like it isn't getting removed but hidden and another page is on top of it.

Comment: I have found the answer of  my question my own. Here I am posting the code snippet to fix this.

   Ext.getCmp('tabpanelpageId').setActiveItem(0);

If you have the three tabs then

 My Name    :   index 0
 My Dptt    :   index 1
 My Loct    :   index 2